# Heat conduction across 2 solids with large thermal condcutivity difference

Tags: thermal-conductivity

I am solving a transient heat condcution problem involving 2 solids using implicit finite difference method.
[image]

At the interface, I soppose the finite difference equation at the interface should be
$$ \frac{k_1(T_{i-1}-T_i)}{\Delta x}=\frac{k_2(T_{i}-T_{i+1})}{\Delta x}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2}(\rho_1Cp_1+\rho_2Cp_2)\frac{T^{n+1}_i-T^n_i}{\Delta t}=k_1\frac{T^{n+1}_{i-1}-T^{n+1}_i}{\Delta x^2}+k_2\frac{T^{n+1}_{i+1}-T^{n+1}_i}{\Delta x^2}$$
The thernmal conducvivities of the 2 solids are 0.5 and 400, and $\rho_1Cp_1$ and $\rho_2Cp_2$ are assumed to be equal. But when I solved the problem using the following code (in Matlab), the result is unexpected. That is, the heat transfer performance of the 2 solids with $k_1=0.5$ and $k_2=400$ is worse than $k_1=k_2=0.5$.

So I am wondering if there is any special criteria need to be applied if the difference between $k_1$ and $k_2$ is huge?

---

Edit:$\rho$, $Cp$, and $k$ are density, heat capacity, and thermal conductivity, respectively. And subscripts 1,2 stand for the two materials. The second equation above is based on the enery conservation over the control volume $i-\frac{1}{2}\Delta x \backsim i+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x$

$$\rho_1Cp_1\frac{1}{2}A\Delta x\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\rho_2Cp_2\frac{1}{2}A\Delta x\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=(k_1A{\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}})_{x\rightarrow i^-}+(k_2A{\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}})_{x\rightarrow i^+}$$
where the L.H.S. is the energy change rate inside the control volume, the R.H.S. is the heat flux injected into the control volume, and $A$ is the unit area.

```
clear all
L=1;
d=0.5;%model dimension
dx=d/40;%grid size

GN=d/dx+1;%interface position
N=L/dx+1; %total grid number

rho1=900;
cp1=2000;
k1=0.5;
rho2=900;
cp2=2000;
k2=400;
a1=k1/(rho1*cp1);
a2=k2/(rho2*cp2);%thermomechanical properties

Time=100000; %total time
dt=1;%time step
alpha=dx^2/dt;

T0=273.15+25;%initial temperature
Tb=273.15+100;%boundary temperature
Ntime=round(Time/dt);%time steps
theta=zeros(Ntime,N);%temperature field history
T=T0*ones(1,N);%initial temperature
T(:,1)=Tb;%LHS B.C.
T2=T;
R=1;

for p=1:1:Ntime
    p
theta(p,:)=T;
while (R>10e-5)
  T3=T2;
  for i=2:1:GN-1
      T2(i)=(a1*(T2(i-1)+T2(i+1))+alpha*T(i))/(alpha+2*a1);
  end
  T2(GN)=(k1*T2(GN-1)+k2*T2(GN+1))/(k1+k2);
  for i=GN+1:1:N-1
      T2(i)=(a2*(T2(i-1)+T2(i+1))+alpha*T(i))/(alpha+2*a2);
  end
  T2(N)=(a2*(T2(N-1)+T2(N-1))+alpha*T(N))/(alpha+2*a2);
 
  R=max(abs(T3-T2)) ;
 
end
T=T2;
R=1;
end
```

Comment: Please clarify: Give the meanings of the variables you are using. ($\rho$, $C$, $k$ ...) The conditions you give look like a) continuity of the heat flux over the boundary, which may be reasonable, and b) a mangled version of the bulk equation at the boundary, which seems weird. But this assessment really would have to depend on the physical meaning of the variables...

Comment: There is forum with Matlab code discussion on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: U mean $C_p$ with a subscript, right? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Ok, so for the physical model alone, before implementation in the simulation, the second equation you give for the boundary condition is unnecessary at vanishing interface thickness (which one would be tempted to assume for simplicity) because it becomes the first equation, right? (In the equation in the edit the left-hand side vanishes for $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$.)

Comment: @kricheli Yes, you are correct. I think I have found the problem: the time step cannot be too big at the interface. Thanks for your help.